# Unable connect Azure apache Kafka server from Azure Databricks Notebook

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-kafka, azure-databricks, apache-kafka-connect

I am in situation not able to create a connection between Azure Data bricks and Azure Kafka server.
Below are my resources.

1. Azure apache kafka server with VM::
   ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYnWX.png)) Settings:

   1. It is installed with default network configuration. Not using any customize Vnet, Subnet and NSG.
   2. Having Public IP and added port 22 and 9092 are added in Inbound rule.
   3. Databricks IP and Local Machine public IPs are added in Just in time in network.
   4. The OS is ubuntu.
2. Azure databricks:: This recource is deployed with standard license and default network configuration. Not using any customize Vnet, Subnet and NSG.

**Note::** [Both are deployed under same resource group and region]

Issue::

```py
df = (spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "**.***.***.*:22")
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config","kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='' password=''")
  .option("subscribe", "spark-events")
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .load()
)

df.display()
```

- **Error::**

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: describeTopics
```

1. I have whitelisted my local machine IP and databricks Ip [Get this IP by using `%sh curl -s ifconfig.me from notebook`].
2. I am able to connect the Kafka VM from my local machine and able to create a 'Topic' after staring zookeeper and kafka-server service.
3. When I am trying use the same ssh command from Databricks [`%sh ssh sparkingestion@**.***.***.* -p 22 sshpass -p abcd`] and getting below error

**Host key verification failed..

```
Note:[ In summary I am not able to connect KAFKA SERVER/VM from DATABRICKS usinf KAFKA CONNECTOR or SSH command.]
```